Did Japan have one of the first secular animal protection laws globally?
Tokugara Tsunayoshi is known to have enacted laws for the protection of animals or living things and is nicknamed "the dog shogun" for that. The Britannica claims, it contained the death penalty on harming a dog., while World History explains those laws as part of a series of much wider edicts that they call the "Edicts on Compassion for Living Things". This leads down a rather fast lane to an Article "The Laws of Compassion" by Beatrice Bodart Bailey.
The Laws of Compassion - a short summary
This article tells some about the legislative history and contemporary talk around the group of laws that are commonly called Shorui Awaremi no Rei. Dating the first ones is tricky, but it seems that the first instances came around the declaration as shogun, so shortly after 1680, and for sure before 1691, as that year the Westphalian physician Engelbert
Kaempfer wrote a report that explained said laws of compassion.
The article explains, that the first laws of this series increased legal protections for minors (including a registry of pregnant women and children under 7 to prevent infanticide). Other laws of the series provide minimum standards in prisons. The first animal protection law, according to that article, banned cutting horse sinews to force a different walk and docking horse tails. These two orders were enacted in or around October/November 1680.
The set of laws also contained fishery regulations, which seem very wide-sweeping at first (a ban on trailing-hook fishery) but are a limitation of fishing to professional fishermen and banning recreational or personal fishing without a license. Similar regimes were put up for hunting game. One of the accepted reasons among historians was to protect the animal reserves, not a privilege for nobles, making these appear very modern. The licensing regimes survived many other Laws of Compassion when those were relaxed under later shoguns.
As for dogs... Let's quote Kaempfer's accord of Japan

On punishment of death nobody may maltreat or kill dogs, except for the bailiff when the
dogs themselves have committed a crime and deserve to be killed.


At the bank of the castle moat we passed the place for public notices, where a
new proclamation together with twenty Shuits of silver had just been posted. The
silver is to be given as a reward to anyone coming forth with the name of
anybody killing a dog, for such acts are sometimes punished.

Legislative Intent
Bailey claims the legislative intent of the laws was not just a protection of dogs or animals, but because banning cruelty in general would foster better, more gentle people:

Again and again shogunal orders
emphasized that the new laws were not issued simply to protect animals. Their
purpose was more profound. The shogun wished to foster the spirit of
benevolence in the hearts of his people and he hoped to achieve this goal by
ordering them to treat all animate creation with care and gentleness. 18
18 - 8 See, for instance, SJ, 1, pp. 250B, 257B-
58A & 272B; Shively, 'Tokugawa Tsuna-
yoshi', p. 113.

So in effect, we can't see it as a religious law, but have to see it as a secular law.
Question Restatement
So, we know that by 1680, there were secular laws for the protection of animals for secular reasons in Japan. But does that make Japan the first example of such laws? Were there other examples before, that were not enacted not to formalize some religious taboo?

We should be compassionate towards all living things, therefore you will be executed if you harm a dog...  Anyway, Egyptians are known to have revered cats so it is highly likely the preceded Japan by a few millennia, although perhaps you'd consider such thing religious based?

@MichaelHall Egyptian's cat worship was religious in nature, the laws were part of the religious ban. If you read the linked Bailey article, it would tell you that these laws were not religious in nature at all, but often enough served (at least in part) secular means or even simply preservation means (or a licensing scheme)

The dog protection laws were, so Bailey, having the most problem to be enforced, which was the reason they were not only re-enacted the most often, but also had the most draconic punishments.

You might get better answers at History.SE, even though this question isn't strictly off topic. It is rare for modern laws to have strong continuity back that far, and lawyers and people trained in law tend to have weak knowledge of laws going that far back in time (especially outside of England).

@ohwilleke You mean unless it is to discuss roman law or medieval english law? Yes, history might be a good place to ask though.

@Trish Just so.

I actually think both the question and @DaleM's answer are on topic, and very interesting to read. Especially to those of us who aren't lawyers but like to learn more about the legal frameworks and how they work. Thank you Trish.

No
But not because there were earlier ones than the ones you cite (there may or may not have been); rather they were as much religious prohibitions as secular ones. The Shogun issued edicts in the name of the Emperor - and the Emperor was a god, so those edicts were religious. The divinity of the Emperor only ended, and the beginning of a purely secular government of Japan only happened with the adoption of the post-World War II constitution on 3 May 1947.
More generally, the distinction between secular crime and religious sin dates back to the 18th century and was not fully established in Western countries until the late 20th century. For example, the UK had blasphemy laws into the 1970s. Indeed, a cogent argument could be made that ostensibly secular laws about reproduction in the modern USA are religiously based.
It is difficult and important not to adopt too much of a modern mindset when considering historical events. We can think of a distinction between the religious and the secular, but for people in the pre-Enlightenment era, such a distinction would not make sense.

Your argument is that when the government is a theocracy, all laws can be considered religious, regardless of whether they actually refer to the religion's doctrine?

@Barmar no, my argument is that before the enlightenment period, everything was religious.

Ugh. When will users stop trying to outsmart OPs?

@DaleM Sorry, but the "before enlightenment everything was religious" just is wrong on many many levels. Just a single example of that the split existed in europe: The Concordat of Worms of 1122 differentiated very clearly between the secular and the clergy - and that a bishop that was appointed by the pope as a clergyman would have to be given his secular title and land as a lord by the secular ruler. For japan, while the Shogun was appointed by the tenno, the whole bafuku was secular and separate from the different clergy groups (buddhist and shinto groups mostly).

Secular just means "This is unrelated or neutral to religion", not separated from Religion. Think about land taxes to the worldly rulers: those are and always have been secular. On the other hand the very similar tithe to the clergy always was religious in nature.
